# PySerial : weird output with letter and quotation marks

Tags: python, pyserial

so I am trying to use Python to read values from a DS18B20 temperature sensor on my Arduino board. In my python code, I use Pyserial to access the port, below is the code.

```
import serial
def readTemp():
    temp = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
    line = temp.readline().strip()
    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        line = temp.readline().strip()
    temp.close()

def main():
    readTemp()

main()
```

In my Arduino code, I code it so that the output should be numeric.Below is the output from Arduino:

```
21.3125
22.3750
22.3750
22.3750
22.3750
```

However, when I run the Python code, the output is added some letter and quotation marks, but I do not know why and how to remove them. Below is the output from Python.

```
b'22.3750'
b'22.0625'
b'22.0625'
b'22.0625'
b'22.0625'
```

Secondly, normally when people run a python script on the shell, there will be a '>>' to indicate that the running process has finished, and then the shell can be closed. However, after the output of my python script is printed, the script seems still running as there is no '>>' appeared. I try to use ctrl+c to kill but unable to, and when I try to close the shell there is a pop up window said 'your program is still running, do you want to kill it?'. So are there anyways to finish running after the output is printed?

I am new to Python, and just learned pyserial. Thank you very much and I will appreciate your help.

Comment: The reading command is blocking. So each time you get to the while there will be a value in line. There's nothing that will make the loop exit.  As for the extra characters: I don't see them in the output you posted, so it's hard to tell. But please check the complete configuration of the serial port: baudrate, number of bits, stop bits,...

Comment: Thank you very much! So I basically put the readline() command at the beginning of the loop and it worked pretty well. For my first question, as the you can see the answer below, the ordinary outcome of readline() is in bytes, and I have to change it into string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first question,

Don't worry, the values are read as bytes. **b** infront of it denotes bytes. You can convert it to string
using **decode('utf-8')**.

Change required in code

Replace

```
print(line.strip())
```

with

```
bytesValue = line.strip()
numericValue = int(bytesVale.decode('utf-8'))
print(numericValue)
```

Regarding second question,
Your process is not finished as it is listening to the device.
The condition

```
while line:
```

keeps the process alive.

If you want the program to just read a value and exit, you can use **if** instead of **while**.

```
line = temp.readline().strip()
if line:
        bytesValue = line.strip()
        numericValue = int(bytesVale.decode('utf-8'))
        print(numericValue)
temp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  Like you see, I have 5 lines in Arduino output that need to be read, if I use ‘if’ instead of ‘while’, it will only read the first output. So with your advice, I replace it with a ‘for’ loop( as I already know the number of lines in Arduino output) and shift the readline() command to the beginning of the loop. The output turns out well. Thank you again!